Handshake Failure in ASP.NET Core Web API on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that was working perfectly on my Windows machine. I needed to deploy it on an Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS server. I followed this guide.
The application runs and can be accessed through the browser using localhost:5169. in Linux However, when a client tries to fetch data using the Linux server's IP address and port endpoint, it throws the following exception: I am using HTTP currently
Client Window app access then this exception shows in the terminal of Linux. If I use Client android app then it does not throw any exception it just says Time out.
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
> An error occurred using the connection to database '****' on server '******'.
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type '****.ApiContext.apiContext'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream........

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.2 (Installed)
Added this is Program.cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls; var app = builder.Build();

Connection String

"ApiString": "Data Source=DB***;Initial Catalog=;User Id=user;Password=*******;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;Persist Security Info=false;Application Intent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=false"

LaunchSettings.Json
`"profiles": {
"Image_catalogue": {
"commandName": "Project",
"launchBrowser": true,
"launchUrl": "swagger",
"environmentVariables": {
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
},
"dotnetRunMessages": true,
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5169",
"nativeDebugging": false
},

`
Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Which version of openssl, and on the server which version of Windows and SQL Server? Why are you setting SecurityProtocol manually, that is only going to make things worse?

Couple of stuff you might need to check. First of all, ensure the port is open and accessible, verify database connectivity from the Ubuntu server, install necessary SSL libraries (libssl-dev), and confirm SQL Server supports the required TLS version. Update your Program.cs to explicitly set the TLS version. In addition, enable detailed logging in your appsettings.json to gain more insights, and double-check your connection string configuration.

This solution worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
